# How to terminate performSelectorInBackground: thread?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

How can I kill a thread created by `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` from the main thread? I need to force termination of freezing threads.

Comment: How do you know that it's "frozen" and not just taking a very very very very very long time to execute? (And if you can successfully answer that, you will have solved one of the greatest problems of all time)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot kill background threads from the main thread, the method that is executing in a background thread has to return for the thread to end.

Your actual problem seems to be that your background thread is freezing, you should solve that instead of trying to work around it.

Comment: +1 for "Your actual problem seems to be that your background thread is freezing, you should solve that instead of trying to work around it."

Comment: So what you just do a return in your background method once you want it to stop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this may help but here goes:

Assuming you're calling that `performSelector` call from class A. And assuming that class A is about to be released from memory in class B (which is where if the selector hasn't been performed yet, you might be getting a crash - Hence you're posting this question on SO):

Wherever you're releasing A from B, do this:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:A];
```

Comment: I also all new 'performSelectorOnMainThread' from 'performSelectorInBackground' thread.

Comment: That helps for methods that are scheduled to be performed with a delay, but not for those already running.

Answer (score 0):

Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW10) says

> The recommended way to exit a thread is to let it exit its entry point
>   routine normally. Although Cocoa, POSIX, and Multiprocessing Services
>   offer routines for killing threads directly, the use of such routines
>   is strongly discouraged. Killing a thread prevents that thread from
>   cleaning up after itself. Memory allocated by the thread could
>   potentially be leaked and any other resources currently in use by the
>   thread might not be cleaned up properly, creating potential problems
>   later.